# Spring MVC 4.1.5 to use image resource in css for styling the view "jsp"

Tags: css, spring-mvc, tiles

//It seems the base.jsp which has the css style can't map/find the location of the resource image :background-image: url("/resources/gearsIcon_logo.png"); Am I wrong in the tiles-servlet.xml configuration or in web.xml.? What should be the right configs in servlet.??By the way the image is in **"src/resources/image.jpg"**

```
    **web.xml**
    ######################### 
    enter code here
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE xml>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/ns/javaee/web-app_4_1.xsd"
    xmlns:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/ns/javaee/web-app_4_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="4.1">

    <display-name>tiles</display-name>
           <servlet>
                  <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
                  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
           </servlet>   

           <servlet-mapping>
                  <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
                  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
           </servlet-mapping>

           <listener>
                  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
           </listener>
           <welcome-file-list>
                  <welcome-file>
                         home.htm
                  </welcome-file>
           </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>

**tiles-servlet.xml**
#################################
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd"
> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller"/>  
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>

**base.jsp**
#########################

this is the jsp file which I embedded my css <style/>
#logo {  
    background-image: url("/resources/gearsIcon_logo.png"); 
     background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -81px;
}
```

//It can't map/find the location of the resource image :background-image: url("/resources/gearsIcon_logo.png"); Am I wrong in the tiles-servlet.xml configuration or in web.xml.? What should be the right configs in servlet.??

Comment: What happens when you try to access the /resources/gearsIcon_logo.png directly in the browser?

Comment: simply no image display....

Comment: Might be naive, but do you try to access it with a servlet context path? What happens when you try to access your image in code like this <c:url value="/resources/gearsIcon_logo.png"/>?

Comment: that didn't work either..by the way i changed image path  now its in WebContent/resources/gearsIcon_logo.png still did'nt work, and with this in tiles-servlet <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller"/>  
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: would you mind uploading your project to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry for very late reply to this post, I got my solution on this.

in my **tiles-servlet.xml** I have put below:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
    cache-period="31556926" />
```

hence: the resource folder is under /Webcotent/resources

and in my **header.jsp** I've addded this:

```
 <spring:url     value="/resources/img/gearsIcon_logo.png" var="img">  
    </spring:url>
```

This solved my misery. Cheers!!